# How to get BIOS serialnumber with WMIC command

Tags: command-line, bios, wmic

Whenever I use the command line below

> wmic bios get serialnumber

It outputs the BIOS Serial number with my laptop.

However, I've tried that command line to get BIOS serial number with my company's PC, I didn't work a bit.

Here was the output:

```
C:\Users\companypc>wmic bios get serialnumber
SerialNumber
System Serial Number
```

So how can I get the BIOS Serial with that problem...

Comment: It may be that the serial number of the computer isn't saved in the BIOS the same way as your personal computer. You may need to try something like CPU-Z or similar to gather hardware information.

Comment: @MichaelFrank: That's great. However, I am looking for the command line or any way which can output the BIOS Serial number to me.

Comment: In that case, what is the make/model of the work PC?

Comment: Try this `wmic csproduct get vendor,name,identifyingnumber`.

Comment: @MichaelFrank: Here they are: `C:\Users\companypc>wmic csproduct get vendor,name,identifyingnumber
IdentifyingNumber     Name                 Vendor
System Serial Number  System Product Name  System manufacturer`

Comment: In that case, it looks either there isn't any information on your computer programmed in, or you don't have the correct permission to view it. Try running `msinfo32`, and on the first page see if there is anything listed under `System ...`. Again, what is the make/model of this PC? Is it OEM, or prebuilt.

Comment: Most likely, this isn't a brand name computer and nobody ever assigned it a serial number.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: So in this case that, I need to assign a serial number for that or how can I do now?

Comment: @PMay1903 You'll have to follow the directions provided by the manufacturer of the motherboard. Usually they provide a tool to allow system builders to assign a serial number.

Comment: Here they are http://upanh.biz/images/2014/07/15/system2UYP9.png

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: This PC was installed and assigned for me and I am so surprise about that because it doesn't have the BIOS serial number even it's a new one with core i5.

Comment: A computer will only have a serial number if the company that made/built it decided it needed one. If it isn't a mass produced model it simply won't need a serial number as there isn't many reasons to identify the computer as one complete unit. The individual components will likely have separate warranties with their respective manufacturers.

Comment: @PMay1903 Who made the computer?

Comment: @MichaelFrank: Thank you for your explanation. Hence, in this case, it doesn't have the BIOS serial number as separated component. As a result of this, does it allow to me to set serial for that or not? If it's not, please tell me why? Furthermore, is it impossible if I remove the BIOS serial number with my laptop which has been set by its manufacturer?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: The IT HelpDesk made that PC for me. It has been built and installed already.

Comment: @PMay1903 If the IT desk made this PC for you, does it have a company asset tag? That would be the closest thing you'd get to a serial number on a custom made PC.

Comment: @MichaelFrank: No, It doesn't. My first-day-work is the day that PC has been installed everything completely and perfectly yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> So how can I get the BIOS Serial with that problem.

You do not. You already provided your own answer, however the hardware you have **has no serial number**. People either did not set one at manufacture, or they forgot about it.

This is sadly quite common.

Comment: Is it impossible if I try to remove my BIOS Serial number with my laptop?

Comment: Yes and no. There is a field for the serial number (and other fields for much more information) in many generic BIOSes and methods to read these fields. The person manufacturing the BIOS *should* fill this with the correct information. Unless that is done the fields often read their default values (e.g. "insert manufacturers name here" rather than the proper name. Or "serial number: 000000" etc etc.)

Comment: Sometimes this is a driver issue! Installing the mainboard drivers may resolve the issue and suddenly WMI can query the serial number.

Answer (score 1):

**IF USING POWERSHELL**

First line will grab all params in "Win32_BIOS"

```
$computerBIOS = get-wmiobject Win32_BIOS
```

Second Line will only allow the serial number to show when eriting it to the console

```
$SerialNumber = $computerBIOS.SerialNumber
```

Lastly "Write-Host" will show the serial number straight from the bios

```
write-host $SerialNumber
```

This is the way I use when trying to find serial number of a remote computer at my job. Its pretty much the same concept but your just not looking for a remote serial your looking for a local one.